# Как стереть последнюю напечатанную в консоль строку на C, Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c, консоль

Необходимо для пагинации частями выдавать данные в консоль, нужно стереть `"press any key"` после того как нажата любая клавиша, пробовал разные спецсимволы и переносы кареток, ни чего не помогло, прошу помощи знатоков. Нужно что-то типо как в gdb пагинация со строкой `----more----`.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    while (true) {
        /* какие то полезные данные */
        printf("********\n");
        printf("********\n");
        printf("********\n");
        /* какие то полезные данные */

        printf("press any key\n");
        const int c = getch();
        if (c == 'q') {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выводить без `\n`, при необходимости — с `fflush(stdout)`, а потом, по нажатию — вывод `\r` для возврата в начало строки и работать дальше. Или сразу выводить `press any key\r`. Если первая выводимая после этого строка может оказаться слишком короткой, чтобы забить это `press any key` — вывести предварительно пачку пробелов с `\r`.

Comment: @Harry в `press any key` воткнул `\r` помогло, но не пойму куда пачек пробелов пихнуть чтобы часть `press any key` не оказывалась в следущем выводе

Comment: Пока не перешли на след. строку  `printf("\b \b"); fflush(stdout);` сотрет один последний символ. Можете попробовать -- `printf("\n12345"); fflush(stdout); for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { sleep(1);  printf("\b \b"); fflush(stdout);}`

Comment: `printf("press any key\r"); ..... printf("              \r"); вывод того, что нужно.`

Comment: @Harry спасибо, оформите как ответ поставлю плюсик

Comment: @Harry вы схитрили, подменив задачу стирания предыдущей строки на задачу стирания текущей строки :)

Comment: @andreymal Тогда надо страшные системнозависимые телодвижения с консолью делать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
while (true) {
    /* какие то полезные данные */
    printf("********\n");
    printf("********\n");
    printf("********\n");
    /* какие то полезные данные */

    printf("press any key\r");
    fflush(stdout);
    const int c = getch();
    if (c == 'q') {
        break;
    }
    printf("             \r");

    // Продолжение вывода на экран.

}
```